# File transfer in phonegap using bluetooth

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, bluetooth, file-transfer

i am new to phonegap, i would like to know is that possible to transfer text file from one device to another device using bluetooth in phonegap. i have gone through many example but i couldn't find any relevant answer to this.

I had seen few example which can detect nearest bluetooth devices but not about file transfer using bluetooth. Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming it is possible with bluetooth, but I haven't seen any examples.  I'm trying to do the same thing.  Also, none of the cordova bluetooth plugins I've seen support Android, IOS, Windows Phone 8.x and Windows 8.x